# How do I pass a TForm (this) generically?

Tags: c++, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have two almost identical forms (Form4 and Form5) that have several common items but handle different data. 
I am trying to write a helper function that will take either of these forms.

Both forms are created dynamically.

So far I am able to write the function that processes the data from Form4 [Process(TForm4 *F)]. I cannot do the same from Form5 because the helper function is specific to TForm4.

From Form4

```
 Edit1Exit(Tobject *Sender){     
   Process(this);
 }
```

From Form5

```
 Edit1Exit(Tobject *Sender){     
   Process(this);
 }

 Process(TForm4 *F){
  // Do something like F->BitBtn1->Visible=false;
  }
```

The problem is that Process( ) is written for TForm4 so it won't accept TForm5.

How do I declare Process() so that it will take either form.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a template function (or, if you prefer, an overloaded function)..

Comment: Why not derive both TForm4 & TForm5 from a base Form class and pass the base class in as a parameter to your common method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you will have three options:

1. Write an explicit overload for each version, and duplicate the code. I.e.,

```cpp
void Process(TForm4* F) {
   /// do things
}

void Process(TForm5* F) {
   /// do things
}
```

2. Derive from a common base class that declares a virtual interface, i.e.,

```cpp
class TFormBase {
    // common virtual interface, and a virtual destructor
};

class TForm4 : public TFormBase {
    // implementation of the interface + data members
};

class TForm5 : public TFormBase {
    // implementation of the interface + data members
};

void Process(TFormBase* F) {
    // interact with F via the virtual interface
}
```

3. Use templates (but in that case, the implementation of your function has to be accessible where it is used; usually that means it has to live in the header file or in a file that can be included directly), i.e.,

```cpp
template<typename T>
void Process(T* F) {
    // interact with the classes; assumes a common interface
}
```

For simplicity, I've omitted a lot of details, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I could do options 1 and 2, but I didn't see them as being any better than just leaving the code in the form. I haven't used templates before so I didn't think of them. It looks like that will do what I want.

Comment: The second option is a standard patter for object-oriented programming, and it would the the more "canonical" and extensible way of doing this (i.e., if you need to create TForm3 or TForm6 or change the behaviour of one of them slightly while maintaining the interface, thats the way to go). So I wouldn't discount it immediately :) Metaprogramming with templates is not a bad way either, but exposing the implementation and the fact that the code gets compiled repeatedly for different types might be a no-go for some applications.